# In Qtp , an error stating that "Information cannot be retrieved for the selected object" is getting displayed for some objects

Tags: object, qtp

In Qtp , an error stating that "Information cannot be retrieved for the selected object" is getting displayed for some objects. What is the reason and how to proceed. I have tried Re-Associating OR, But still it is not showing the objects in the OR

Answer (score 0):

Check your add-in association, may be that the add-ins are either not loaded or not associated with your test.

To see if add-ins are appropriately associated with your test, GoTo File > Settings > Properties > Associated Add-ins. Verify that your add-ins are there and that the boxes next to them are checked respectively.

If this is not the problem, more information may need to be provided.